# How can an index be a string (i[s])?

Tags: c

```
char s[]="man";

int i; 

for(i=0;s[i];i++)

printf("%c%c%c",i[s],*(i+s),*(s+i));
```

The code might look simple but as a beginner I wasn't able to understand how `i[s]` gives the output. And how `*(i+s)` was giving output as n?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/1216776

Comment: It loops 3 times on ideone... https://ideone.com/9J4czQ

Comment: Asking about the loop operation is a separate question from the subscript issue and ought to be asked in a separately posed question. However, the middle expression of the `for`, `s[i]` causes the loop to continue if and only iff it is not zero. Since `s[i]` is referring to the elements of the string, it has the values `'m'` (which is not zero) in the first iteration, `'a'` in the second (still not zero), `'n'` in the third (also not zero), and `'\0'` in the fourth. This last value is zero, so the fourth iteration is not executed. There is a `'\0'` in the string because `"man"` puts one there.

Answer (score 0):

In C, for expressions `E1` and `E2`, the subscript operation `E1[E2]` is defined to be `*((E1)+(E2))`, which means to add `E1` and `E2` and use the resulting pointer to access an object.

Most often, `E1` is a pointer, and `E2` is an integer, and `(E1)+(E2)` adds the integer to the pointer by producing a pointer that is `E2` elements further along in memory than where `E1` points. However, addition is commutative, so `(E2)+(E1)` is the same as `(E1)+(E2)`. Due to the definition of the subscript operation, this means you can write `E2[E1]` with the same effect.

Note that the subscript operator works only with one pointer and one integer. If you provide an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. This conversion occurs before the subscript operator is applied. Thus, if you have `int array[4]`, then `array[2]` is automatically converted to `p[2]`, where `p` is a pointer with the value `&array[0]`, the address of the first element of `array`.

Similarly, if you write `2[array]`, then `array` is again converted to that `p`, and the result is `2[p]`. By definition, that is `*(2+p)`, so the result is adding 2 to `p` and then referencing the memory that points to, which is the element `array[2]`.